# Toggling on off button does not update the function

Tags: javascript, html, cesiumjs

Using cesium JS, I want to add a button that would use the cesium zoom/camera feature to go to a new point when created and that is using my "myFunction" but I want it to continuously update it's position until the button is clicked again to turn it off.

When someone clicks the button it should toggle the camera to the new points being made and will continue to do so until someone "turns it off" or rather clicks the button again.

I've tried doing this with the code below but when I click the button nothing happens, I have tried using a variable that will get turned either true/false when clicked, and within my other function it will loop the "myFunction" until the button is clicked again or "false" any suggestions?

```js
document.getElementById("camButton").addEventListener("click", myFunction2);
var buttonState = false;
function myFunction2() {
  if (buttonState == false) {
    buttonState = true;
  } else {
    buttonState = false;
  }
}
function myFunction() {
  if (buttonState == false) {
    viewer.camera.flyTo({
      destination: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(
        payload["geometry"]["coordinates"][0],
        payload["geometry"]["coordinates"][1],
        5000000
      )
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: your second function is myFucntion() which is not in use in the provided code. so can you please tell me where your myFucntion() comes from?

Comment: @ShilpeSaxena that's the function that operates the camera movement, and I just want it to continue to call itself while the "buttonState" is true so that it keeps moving until someone clicks the button again to make "buttonState" false, because at the moment it only updates position every time I manually click the button, I do not want to do it manually I want it to keep updating until I turn it off, if that makes sense? sorry im relatively new to coding so sorry if im making beginner mistakes

Comment: no need to sorry it's okay try to add pause(0.1) to your code.

Comment: @ShilpeSaxena where should I add the pause ? just at the bottom or within one of the functions?

Comment: within the function

Comment: Simplified and easier to debug **ASSUMING** you want to fly if the buttonState is FALSE, otherwise you need to swap the test: `let buttonState = false; const toggle = buttonState = !buttonState; document.getElementById("camButton").addEventListener("click", toggle); 
function myFunction() { if (buttonState) return; viewer.camera.flyTo({ destination: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees( payload["geometry"]["coordinates"][0], payload["geometry"]["coordinates"][1], 5000000)}); }`

Comment: @mplungjan thanks so much for your comment, I tried both buttonStates but I am not sure why neither works?

Comment: I cannot help since I do not understand the question. I just tried to make the code simpler. I think you want to interrupt the flight? If so you need to look in the documentation since the flyTo is async and will not know your buttonState.